# Show all rows where value appears at least once in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that's resulting in the following. RN is the Row Number of every time we have a transaction with one of the following IDs. I just want to see IDs of people who had an "A" value in the GROUP.

I tried doing a WHERE statement, but that would just get me rows that have A ... I want to see all ID rows where "A" appeared at least once in the GROUP.

Would this work in a Sub-Query?

```
RN    ID    GROUP
1     001   A
2     001   B
3     001   B
1     002   B
2     002   B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test setup (note that **Group** is a reserved word)

```
create table t(rn NUMERIC(2), id varchar (3), thegroup char)

insert t values(1,'001','A')
insert t values(2,'001','B')
insert t values(3,'001','B')
insert t values(1,'002','B')
insert t values(2,'002','B')
```

Needed query

```
select *
from t
where id in (
  select id
  from t
  where thegroup in ('A')
)
```

Result

```
rn |id  |thegroup |
---|----|---------|
1  |001 |A        |
2  |001 |B        |
3  |001 |B        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "[HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)" clause.

Comment: I would have to do a Group by, but I need to see all rows with that ID that have "A" appearing at least once

Comment: Not suitable for an answer, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option. For this type of logic, I like `WHERE EXISTS` because it's obvious what you're doing with the query. Handy in six months or six years when you have to revisit the code.

`o` and `i` aliases are for `Outer` table and `Inner` table, vis-a-vis the sub-query.

```
select
  o.RN,
  o.ID,
  o.[GROUP]
from 
  mytable as o
where 
  exists(select 1
         from mytable as i
         where i.ID = o.ID
         and i.[GROUP] = 'A');
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/XPBG45217)

Comment: But this would exclude all other rows that have anything else besides A